# Debug port (8700) is busy, make sure there is no other active debug connection to the same application?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I am trying to launch the debugger in android studio, but I keep getting this message. Anybody knows how to resolve that?

```
Debug port (8700) is busy, make sure there is no other active debug connection to the same application
```

Comment: Did you run in debug mode more than once? Go into Run menu, click STOP (`CTRL+F2`)

Comment: Make sure that any other application is not running at the same port like eclipse.

Answer (score 23):

Best less head ache solution is

> File > Invalidate Cache and restart!

Answer (score 1):

In case you feel invalidating cache will require more time to re-build, try this - close the project, restart android studio and re-open the project.